# Why can smoke be seen coming from McCoy's surgery on Sarek? (Journey to Babel, TOS)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

After 03:58 in [this YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INkQsOvrmLo) from Star Trek TOS episode [Journey to Babel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Journey_to_Babel_(episode)) there's a moment where McCoy is performing surgery on Sarek using a static medical arch-like device over Sarek's chest.

At one moment smoke can be seen rising from behind the device, at least in this particular YouTube clip.

**Question:** Why can smoke be seen coming from McCoy's surgery on Sarek?  Is this in-universe smoke, or perhaps a short circuit in a prop, or does DeForest Kelley have a cigarette back there and is sneaking puffs between takes?

---

[image: from Star Trek TOS episode Journey to Babel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INkQsOvrmLo]

Comment: Mentioned but not explained in the *Nitpicker's Guide* - "It almost looks as if someone has a cigarette back there."

Comment: worth noting that its also asked on https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78130/was-the-smoke-in-this-scene-accidental-or-a-practical-effect-serving-to-depict-s - my answer (the correct one imo ;) wasn't there so I added it after answering here

Comment: @OrganicMarble ya it *really does* look just like that. I wonder, did DeForest Kelley smoke? Actually... did anybody not smoke back then?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - https://i.pinimg.com/originals/49/86/5f/49865f7b6c4508137939af4d4ac4e6e1.jpg

Comment: @uhoh  I was alive back then, and older than many kids who start smoking, and I have never smoked.  The surgeon general's report that smoking caused lung cancer came out in 1964, several years earlier, so people who were not already addiction to nicotine had a good not to try it, and many did not.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I grew up in a smoke filled house and lost my parents to lung cancer and heart disease way too early; no need to tell me what the 1960's were like.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [StarTrek.com](https://www.startrek.com/article/your-tos-questions-answered) it's a **deliberate effect** intended as
"*cryogenic fog*" from the cryogenic-surgery (mispronounced as '*serogenic*' in the episode)

> Question: In “Journey to Babel,” Sarek (Mark Lenard) becomes
> critically ill while being transported on the Enterprise and,
> according to Mr. Spock, needs a “serogenic” surgical procedure on his
> heart to repair it. What’s a serogenic surgical procedure?
>
> Answer: That’s a good question. Checking the script, it appears that
> the word “cryogenic” – which relates to very low temperatures – was
> mispronounced as serogenic by Nimoy. Here’s the dialogue from the
> script:
>
> SPOCK
>
> I’d say a cryogenic open-heart procedure is the logical approach.
>
> As further proof that the word cryogenic was intended, the surgery
> that McCoy (DeForest Kelley) later performs on Sarek makes use of a
> “cryosurgical frame” that generates fog from condensed atmospheric
> water caused by the very cold temperature. (**The effect was likely
> created by the effects team using smoke or dry ice**).

hat-tip to https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/journey-to-babel-deforest-kelley-smoking.300756/ for the link

Comment: Wow there's a real world heart treatment called cryoablation that is used to kill tissue causing crazy nerve signals. https://youtu.be/z91_9Si4wQ0

Comment: I'm quite skeptical of the mispronounced word claim as serology is the study of blood serum so serogenic is actually quite appropriate here considering they were taking medicine to ramp up blood cell production.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - the StarTrek.com article quoted claims that it is "cryogenic" in the script.  And the medicine to ramp up blood cell production was taken by *Spock*, so that he could be a blood donor during the surgery, as they did not have the right type (or enough of it) in the blood bank.

Comment: I'm guessing that "cryogenic" got either misspelt or misread as "cyrogenic".  That would sound like "serogenic".

Comment: @AB You may find [this](https://youtu.be/fF6s9hMtMv0) interesting.

Comment: @lucasbachmann if we're being pedantic, a _serogenic_ procedure would be one that _generated_ serum or would describe something created by serum. Since serum does not contain blood cells, if you were to coin a word for a procedure whose aim is to ramp up blood production, you'd opt for something like _haematogenic_ instead or, more likely, the word actually used in our world for such processes: [_hematopoietic_](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/hematopoietic). Either way, _serogenic_ would not be related to blood cells.

Comment: @Basya you are correct save for originally they were considering using the drug on Sarek to bank his own blood for the surgery but the stress would have killed him.  Whatever the procedure is requires a tremendous amount of blood for some reason.  I find it easier to believe in a hypothetical early draft focusing on the blood aspect of the surgery than Nimoy mispronouncing it.  but obviously there's no evidence for it - but it is suspicious that a mispronunciation would be so close to a reasonable alternative scifi medical word.

Comment: It is worth noting that McCoy talks about filtering out the human elements of Spock's blood that you do see tubes with red and green fluids in them.

Comment: @terdon thank you. Spock would approve.